# Remove spaces from all elements of an array

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, sed, whitespace

I've sample file named 'test.in' like below, with leading and trailing spaces:

```
 Hi | hello how | are you?
 I need | to remove | leading & trailing
 spaces |  where  ever   | it's located
```

I need to put the elements separated by "|" in array with "\n" as the main delimiter.

I want that each element in array shouldn't have leading or trailing spaces, only spaces in between characters are allowed. I'm using a sample code to test the results before I put the code is my primary deployment.

Portion of sample script:

```
OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
while read LINE
do
IFS='|'
my_tmpary=($LINE)
echo ${my_tmpary[@]}
my_ary=`echo ${my_tmpary[@]} | awk '$1=$1'`
echo ${my_ary[@]}
done < test.in
```

I would like NOT to use a loop to clean up the extra spaces.
I did trial & error methods using sed, awk, tr, but it's not a success for me yet.

my_ary[@] should be like this

```
Hi hello how are you?
I need to remove leading & trailing
spaces where ever it's located
```

Comment: Your question is not immensely clear at the moment.. Do you wish to trim the spaces around `|`. Anyways it is always good to put a sample output to express yourself better.

Comment: Also `my_ary` is not an array. It just holds the result result of the command `echo ${my_tmpary[@]} | awk '$1=$1'` which is a string.

Comment: Stop, you're approach is completely wrong and you should not even have a shell array. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). If you post a new question with concise testable sample input and expected output we can help you do it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -E 's/[\t]{1,}/ /g;s/^ *| *$//g;s/[ ]{2,}/ /g;s/ *\| */ /g;' test.in
```

should do it. So :

```
$ my_ary=$(sed -E 's/[\t]{1,}/ /g;s/^ *| *$//g;s/[ ]{2,}/ /g;s/ *\| */ /g;' test.in)
$ echo "$my_ary"
Hi hello how are you?
I need to remove leading & trailing
spaces where ever it's located
This lines has many tabs
```

solves your problem.

---

**Notes**
1. `s/[\t]{1,}/ /g` converts the tabs ie `\t` to whitespaces.
2. `s/^ *| *$//g` removes the leading & trailing whitespaces.
3. `s/[ ]{2,}/ /g` squeezes multiple whitespaces to one.
4. `s/ *\| */|/g` removes the spaces around `|`
5. The `-E` enables the use of extended regex with `sed`.

Comment: I think you are correct in assuming that OP also wants to remove spaces before and after `|`.

Comment: @andlrc : Well, I think that is what the op wished to do here, Yeah! :)

Comment: Change to first to `s/^ *\| *$//g` to also handle the trailing spaces.

Comment: I think OP's data contains tabs aswell

Comment: @123 : Thankyou, I have accommodated that with my edit I guess...:)

Comment: @sjsam Like actual tab characters not just multiple spaces, like `\t`.

Comment: @sjsam thanks for the quick answer..  and I like your way to process the file before sending it to read for array, makes the overall processing easier.

Comment: @123 : I see, added that. Please note that I have added `s/[\t]{1,}/ /g` to the beginning as the order matters here.

Comment: You can do that with just `sed -r 's/^\s+|\s+$//g; s/\s+\|?\s+/ /g' file` but again, this is simply the wrong approach to manipulating text with shell.

Comment: Thankyou Ed. I went through the link you have posted above. I see the point now.. @EdMorton

Answer (score 3):

You can (ab)use the fact that read will remove leading and trailing spaces when `IFS` is default:

```
while read -r line; do
  printf "%s\n" "$line" # Leading and trailing spaces are removed.
done < test.in
```

Alternative you can sed for such task:

```
sed 's/^[[:space:]]*\|[[:space:]]*$//g' test.in
```

Comment: printf was a nice touch

Comment: that sed won't work, you are matching the full line, and then using g for some reason.

Comment: @123 There is an alternation (`\|`) in there.

Comment: @andlrc My bad, i though that was accidental as I'm pretty sure they want to trim inbetween `|` not just the start and end of the line.

Comment: @123 I think you might be right, that is why I upvoted sjsam's answer, I'm leaving this here for future reference. As OP's question is not very clear - to me at least :-)

Answer (score 1):

In AWK:

```
awk '{gsub(/^ *| *$|/,"",$0); gsub(/ *\| *| +/," ",$0); print $0}' test.in
```

`gsub(/^ *| *$|/,"",$0)` remove leading and trailing space,
`gsub(/ *\| *| +/," ",$0)` replace space-pipe-space combos and multiple spaces with a single space,
`print $0` print the whole record. $0 could be omitted like @mona_sax commented but for the sake of clarity I left it in code.

Surely it could be looped and each pipe delimited field trimmed separately:

```
awk -F\| -v OFS=" " '       # set input field separator to "|" and output separator to " "
function trim(str) {
  gsub(/^ *| *$/,"",str);   # remove leading and trailing space from the field
  gsub(/ +/," ",str);       # mind those multiple spaces as well
  return str                # return cleaned field
} 
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)        # loop thru all pipe separated fields
    printf "%s%s", trim($i),(i<NF?OFS:ORS) # print field and OFS or  
}                                          # output record separator in the end of record
' test.in
```

.

Comment: `print $0` is redundant. `print` by default means `print $0`. Also remove the tabs in the input.

Comment: @mona_sax and you can also say `awk '{gsub(...)}1' file`. This `1` (or any other True value) evaluates to True and triggers the `{print $0}`.

Comment: @fedorqui : Of course you can ! :D That is even more idiomatic & elegant way of doing it.